# Sentence configuration: not real or true and imaginary

Tags: word-usage

Is the following definition correct?

> Fiction is something that is not real or true and imaginary.

Does the *not* modify imaginary as well as "real or true" thus say that fiction is "not" "imaginary"?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the intended meaning of the example sentence is:

> Fiction is something that is imaginary, not something that is real or true.

The construction "not real or true and imaginary." is ambiguous. The form "Not X or Y and Z" could mean:

- Neither X nor Y, but always Z
- Neither X, nor Y and Z (Y and Z considerd as a unit)
- Neither X, nor Y, nor Z (careless, but possible)

Since it is at best awkward, a different construction would be better.

Answer (score 0):

No, "Fiction is something that is not real or true and imaginary" is not correct. The *not* does modify the 'imaginary' here.

So, it should be rephrased as something like 'Fiction is something that is not real or true; it is something imaginary'.